# Other options for a 2x2x2 RCT design that would require less participants

Tags: experiment-design, clinical-trials, pre-post-comparison

Alright, imagine the following:

I would like to assess (the main effect & interplay of) three independent variables (i.e. A, B, and C) on a dependent variable Y. In addition, each independent variable has two levels (i.e. low/high). Furthermore, I will be using a pre- and post-measurement questionnaire in order to assess the baseline of both the independent variables and the dependent variable, and a manipulation check for the independent variables.

Preferably this would be conducted with a 2x2x2 RCT design, in which there are eight conditions plus one control condition. However, this would require too many participants to receive an appropriate effect size.

So now the question; I was wondering what your ideas are on the following:

Instead of a 2x2x2 design with nine conditions, I could maybe conduct the experiment with only two conditions, in which there is a treatment condition (i.e. A, B, and C as one independent variable) and a control condition. Subsequently I could indicate differences in A, B, and C with the use of the pre- and post-measurements (e.g. participants with a high score in A score higher on Y, than participants with high scores in B and C).

The advantage of the latter design is that it would require less participants.